# Something to keep the fizz of cola bottle

Tags: home, food, substitute-tool, technology

I am looking for some trick or gazzette to keep a bigger bottle of coke longer so that it doesn't lose all the fizz everytime it's opened again! Something which could keep the CO2 longer so that a bigger bottle could be used longer? 
Anything we have?

Answer (score 2):

You can get a little pump that attaches to the top of the bottle.

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Jokari-Fizz-Keeper-Pump-2-Litre-Bottles/dp/B00004XSH3

[image: Fizz-Keeper Pump Cap]

It pumps in air to pressurize the bottle, thus preventing the carbon that makes the drink fizzy from escaping the liquid.

Comment: I have one of these, the whole point is that it pumps air _out_ creating a vacuum

Comment: Must be different to that one. Those pump air in. If they pumped it out the plastic bottle would be crushed.

Comment: it would depend how far you pumped it - the liquid stops the bottle crushing in on itself

Comment: Consider when the bottle is only 10% full and you pump all the air out.

Comment: i agree, depends how much you pump out.; if you pump air out you create a vacuum; if you pump all the air our, the bottle will collapse until the liquid wont allow it to collapse any more . I don't see the point you make; if you wish your soda to stay fizzy using this device a somewhat un-aesthetically pleasing bottle is inevitable.

Comment: @bigbadmouse You are mistaken. There is no vacuum created. This pumps air ***into*** the container to conserve the high pressure to keep the CO2 in solution. The pressure is greater than the ambient. The containers are designed to be under pressure. You may be mistaking vacuum pumps for wine bottles which can withstand negative pressure without collapsing. Further, still wine must not pressurized. Sparkling wine is stored under pressure; (more pressure than this plastic pump can generate or hold) so try to re-cork it if you can to conserve it. Better; finish the whole bottle with friends.

Comment: Does this actually work? I thought partial pressure gas laws meant the CO₂ would still escape, and would not be prevented by adding high pressure nitrogen/oxygen (air).

Comment: They work, they aren't perfect but they make your fizzy drink last much longer.

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit more involved, but you can get a carbonator cap.  We use it in homebrewing to carbonate beer and to keep it carbed.  It allows you to hook up a co2 tank to a 2 liter bottle.  You would need the cap, a regulator and a co2 tank or cartridges.

cap: https://www.homebrewing.org/CarbaCap_p_108.html
co2 regulator: https://www.morebeer.com/products/co2-injector-ball-lock.html

Answer (score 1):

Colas go "flat" because of loss of CO2. The only way to keep the CO2 in solution is to prevent it from getting out. While the bottle is sealed, the liquid reaches an equilibrium where the partial pressure of CO2 outside the liquid (but still inside the bottle - the little "air" space at the top) is equal to the partial pressure of CO2 inside the liquid.

As soon as the bottle is opened, the partial pressure of CO2 in the "air" space drops and you see CO2 effervescing from the liquid. This is the liquid's attempt to reach equilibrium again. While the cap is off, equilibrium will not be reached until the CO2 in the liquid is equal to that of ambient air (about 0.04% - aka "flat"). Putting the lid back on helps limit this process, but will NOT prevent the liquid from losing its "fizz". The liquid will reach another equilibrium point after some time at which, the concentration of CO2 in the liquid has dropped in order to stabilize the concentration of CO2 in the air space.

The pressurization gadget mentioned at the very top of the responses does NOT work at all as it does next to nothing to add CO2 to the air space. Ambient air is about 0.04% CO2. You will not be able to pressurize the bottle with enough air to prevent the release of CO2 from the liquid. Not possible.

The only way to prevent the liquid form going "flat" is to introduce CO2 at the same rate at which it leaves. This means you need a system that injects CO2 into the bottle as the liquid is poured out. I'm not aware of anything that does this at the moment.

Comment: Hi Mit, Welcome to Lifehacks.StackExchange. We hope you enjoy sharing knowledge and experience. You can find out more about the site by visiting the [help] and https://www.lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is cola acidic enough to breakdown seashells?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to keep 2ltr cold drinks fizzy is to save 4 x  500ml water bottles and transfer the drink into those. Huge price saving as well over the 500ml soda.

Answer (score 0):

If you buy your soda in a big plastic bottle, I recommend squeezing out as much air as you can before you screw the cap back on. My theory is that the carbonation *wants* to leave the soda, but if there is nowhere for it to go (no big pocket of air in the bottle), then the carbonation will stay in the soda.

(I'll determine whether my theory is right by the number of thumbs up and thumbs down I get on this answer.)

Comment: I'm up-voting you back to zero as I see no difference at all between your method and the air removal pump method - except yours is cheaper.

Comment: I think this is counterproductive, because carbon dioxide is kept in solution at an equilibrium based on pressure. If you squeeze out the air in the bottle, the soda will lose more carbon dioxide before pressure begins to build and equilibrium is reached.

Comment: Sorry Brett, but piojo is correct. Squeezing the air out is worse than simply recapping the partially-filled bottle for the reason piojo gives.

Comment: @Stan Makes sense, now that I think about it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A bottle of soda will lose it's fizz if it is opened when warm,so when you decide to open a large bottle,the first thing to do is to refrigerate it. When the bottle is cold, you can open it and pour the soda. Don't let it get warm after you open it. Pour the soda, re-cap it,then put the entire bottle back in refrigerator. From then on,the way to pour servings of soda will be:

- take bottle from refrigerator
- pour soda
- re-cap bottle
- put bottle in refrigerator

Comment: This is essentially piojo's answer in point form.

Comment: I'm all for explaining the chemistry behind things,but this exchange is Lifehacks and not Chemistry. I don't think a chemical explanation is supposed to be here.

Answer (score 0):

We all know that for each time it's opened some fizz escapes. Reducing the number of times it is opened (or handled) therefore reduces the amount of fizz escaping.

One way for a larger bottle to retain fizz can therefore be to divide the contents into several smaller bottles, so as to reduce the number of openings before actually being consumed.

Note that this should be done with the beverage being as cold as possible to reduce loss of fizz when pouring to the other container(s).

Answer (score 0):

**Keep the bottle *cold* and in an *upright position*. If you drink the coke within a day or two, it will keep fresh and sparkling, and you should hardly notice the difference.**

Tip: The more coke there is inside the bottle (and the less air), the less CO2 will escape from the coke and into the (closed) bottle while it is stored in the fridge (results from Henry's law). Pour over coke from a half-full bottle over to a smaller container (or into another half-full bottle of coke, to fill one single bottle), and you will save space and loose less sparkling gas.

[image]

#### Some theory

CO2 "evaporation" is a result of the gas trying to reach an equilibrium between what is solved in the liquid (coke) and what is in the air above (Henry's law).

Keep in mind:

1. Less CO2 escapes if the *temperature is kept low* (CO2 is more 'soluble' in low temperature, and less will escape from the liquid)
2. Less CO2 escapes if the *bottle is kept upright* (smaller surface area than when the bottle is laid down, so this will slow down the 'evaporation' process)
3. Less CO2 escapes if the *bottle is almost full* (smaller 'air' volume to fill with CO2 escaping from the liquid)

Also remember:

The moment you have opened a bottle of coke, then non-sterile air from the surroundings mixes with the content inside the bottle. An opened container will only keep fresh (without growth of bacteria or fungus) for a limited number of time (a week or two).

Answer (score 0):

CO2 cannot escape if the gas pressure in the bottles open space is high, it does not matter if the gas is air, or CO2.  Pump in some regular air pressure and it will keep the CO2 from escaping.

I'm sure someone sells a device that will allow one to pressurize the bottle and thus keep the CO2 from escaping out of the drink.

[Here](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Jokari-Fizz-Keeper-Pump-Cap-2-Liter-Lt-Soda-Pop-Bottles-Saves-Carbonation-2-Pack/27662392?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=18084&&adid=22222222227018745115&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=146932430806&wl4=pla-256720173014&wl5=1018439&wl6=&wl7=&wl8=&wl9=pla&wl10=126804529&wl11=online&wl12=27662392&veh=sem&gclid=CjwKCAiAoOz-BRBdEiwAyuvA65YMea_25cAYUmBgR5-8-hAIYhPyeP4-vTbs9yxAlZsFWKuGqJ8UDBoCP3cQAvD_BwE) is a link to a device sold at a major retailer to pressurize a soda bottle with regular air and it saves the carbonation.

By the way, I ordered two of these today I can use them.

Comment: That answer has already been given.